# How can a user edit the work sheet but can not save an additional copy or print the file?

Tags: excel

How can a user edit the work sheet but can not save an additional copy or print the file?

Comment: I would say that is not possible. There is always a way how to make a copy of file

Comment: @PavelJanicek Would this be possible by maybe using an access database?

Comment: You can make programs which allow only to enter values, not providing saving copy. But for experienced user there is always a way how to go around it (see the whole software piracy industry for good example). Best way would be to define WHO the user will be and make security "good enough"

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Overall preventing from copying and printing is impossible. But you can make it hard for user to copy or print a file, thus making it "impossible" for unexperienced users

1) You can [protect specific areas from editing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-HA010096837.aspx)

2) after reading [this forum message](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/40026-how-disable-print-copy-worksheet.html) it even seems that you can protect it from copying and printing.

Copypasting the answer from the forum:

For the cancel print part, right mouse over the excel icon to the left of "File" and select "view code" and paste this in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

And for the cancel copy, right mouse over the sheet tab (i.e. Sheet1) and select view code and paste this in, you will be able to copy but when you select another cell it will be cancelled...

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

But as I told earlier: Experienced users will find out way how to workaround it, so try to count with the option that the protection will be broken.